# Creating Table in mysql with Text data type

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I am creating a table in mysql, but when i add column data type as text mysql define it as a primary key.

Can any one tell me what has to be done so that primary key is not get enabled on TEXT data type.

Comment: Can you please show your query?

Comment: Your problem is with the DDL for table creation.  This is a very bad way of asking question, ie. without any detail. Change your question with details of how you are creating, what query is getting executed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am nearly sure that you must define the length of the key. The max length is 767 bytes for a key.

```
CREATE TABLE `long` (
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data`(100))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I don't want to define the TEXT data type as primary, but mysql is doing it by itself.

Comment: MySQl do not define a key itself. It is possible that your client do this.